# How do I change a washer in an outdoor spigot where you can't remove the valve?

Tags: plumbing, leaks

I've replaced washers in spigots before, but this one has me stumped.  There is no nut to remove the valve from the body as far as I can see.  The faucet will not shut off.  Not just a drip, but a steady stream. [image: Faucet]

Comment: Funny, looking at the spigot, I didn't notice the top was a "nut". Looks clearer in the picture. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The part just below the packing nut will unscrew by using a wrench or a small pipe wrench.

Comment: Yep, like the whole top of the spigot body that the shaft enters will turn.  You may have to remove the handle and the packing nut to get a good grip on it - depends on the size of the packing nut.